# Possible to take online classes in a university in a different country without Visa?

Tags: canada, legal-concepts, f1-visa

So someone pointed out to me that there's an extremely cheap site for online classes, but it's in another country. If the classes are online and enrollment can be done via the internet, would one still legally need a Student Visa for this? Often I only hear of needing a Visa when you actually study abroad -- in this case it would be studying right at home and earning college credits from an abroad location, but I wouldn't necessarily need to be abroad myself. In such a case, how does this work?

Is it still the same thing? I ask because I've done work via internet platforms for people abroad, and even though it's technically being paid from another person's money in another country legally without a Visa (thanks to the "middleman" who converts/exchanges and allows this kind of international work connections), I initially thought that, since it's all via the internet, no law would dictate this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You need a visa to travel to another country (unless there is a treaty between your country and their country that waives this e.g. Australia and New Zealand, the EU). If you aren't traveling there is no visa requirements.

Technically the education is exported/imported and, like a TV, it doesn't need a visa.